# Why did Jesus begin his ministry at age 30?

Tags: jesus, luke, christology, chronology

Luke 3:23 (ESV)

> 23 Jesus, when he began his ministry, was about **thirty years of age**, being the son (as was supposed) of Joseph, the son of Heli,

Why did Jesus begin his ministry when he was about 30 years old? Why not earlier? Why not later? What was he waiting for and why?

Comment: There is essentially no record of Jesus's life between his birth and approximately this time, so it would be difficult to know. IMO he probably became a student of John the Baptist for a while and then started his own mission, but this was later revised by the evangelists, who wanted John to be subservient to Jesus.

Comment: John the Baptist began his ministry sometime during the Emperor's fifteenth year. Whether it was at the beginning of his 15th year, or middle, or toward the end of his 15th year I don't know. Then, some months after John the Baptist's ministry began, Jesus appeared to be baptized Luke wrote he was "about" 30 years old, not that he was thirty years old. It could mean he was about to turn thirty years of age or he was either 29 or 31 years old. I don't know for sure if that is correct. But it doesn't say he was thirty but *about* thirty.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Why did Jesus begin his ministry at age 30?**

Jesus a sympathetic High Priest that can sympathize with our weaknesses. For this reason, he came to earth born as a man having flesh and blood, and experiencing life as a human, having feelings and emotions at first hand.

Hebrews 4:15  (NASB)

> 15 For we do not have a **high priest** who cannot sympathize with our
> weaknesses, but One who has been tempted in all things just as we are,
> yet without sin.

Why 30 years?

The census of the Kohathites taken at Mount Sinai indicated that the service for priesthood included those between the ages of 30-50.

Numbers 4:2-3 (NET Bible)

> 2 “Take a census[a] of the Kohathites from among the Levites, by their
> families and by their clans, 3 from thirty years old and upward to
> fifty years old, all who enter the company[b] to do the work in the
> tent of meeting.

The following are from the footnotes Numbers 4:3 NET Bible.

The second census of Levites now will **focus on those between 30 and 50 years of age,** those who were actually in service. These are the working Levites. The duties here will be more specific for each of the families. The Kohathites, although part of the ordinary ministry of Levites, were a special group chosen to handle the most holy furnishings. J. Milgrom shows three aspects of their service: (1) skilled labor (מְלָאכָה, melaʾkhah) or “work,” (2) physical labor (עֲבֹדָה, ʿavodah) or “service,” and (3) **assisting the priests (שָׁרֵת, sharet) or “ministering”**

Comment: Good answer.  Also remember that Job asked questions like this of God.

Comment: Peace and Blessings, I have three questions: Was that verse specifically speaking of the Priests or the Kohathites who were not descendants of Aaron?  Why did the Levites begin their ministry at 30 years of age (and then have it changed to 20yers by King David).  Also wasn't Christ a priest after the order of Melchizedek and under/after the Aaronic Priesthood, does that still suffice?

Comment: Gen. 46:11 " And the sons of Levi: Gershon, Kohath, and Merari.The service of the Levites at the sanctuary began at age 25 (reduced in King David’s time to 20). (Num.  8:24; 1 Chr 23:24)

Comment: @OzzieOzzie That being said why was his ministry begun at 30 and not 20 (or 25)?

Comment: Correction: I meant to write "Also wasn't Christ a priest after the order of Melchizedek and "not" under/after the Aaronic Priesthood.

Comment: The duties for the priesthood was at 30, for other duties and services to the sanctuary was 25, later lowered to 20 by King David. Correct the first priest of Salem mentioned in the scriptures and appointed by God was Melchizedek (Heb 6:20 and 5:10)  Aaron was also honored because God also called him for the priesthood.( Heb. 5:1, 4-6)  Covenant to Be a Priest Like Melchizedek  and applied to Jesus by Paul read: Ps 110:4, Heb:7:1-3, 15-17 and Luke 22:29

Comment: הודה :Christ a priest  was after the order of Melchizedek .Melchizedek, at Salem, where he was king as well as priest, seems to be timeless. (Genesis 14:18-20) The life possibility of the resurrected Jesus Christ is likened to that of King-Priest Melchizedek, for Hebrews 7:15-17.(Heb 6:20) 
Other reasons that Jesus' priesthood was superior to the Aaronic priesthood. Jesus as a descendent from David, he becomes the heir of the kingship promised in the Davidic covenant. (2 Sam. 7:11-16) He, therefore, holds in combination the offices of kingship and priesthood, as did Melchizedek

Comment: .In another way the surpassing excellence of Christ’s high priesthood is shown, namely, in that Levi, the progenitor of the Jewish priesthood, in effect, gave tithes to Melchizedek, for Levi was still in the loins of Abraham when the patriarch gave a tenth to Salem’s priest-king. Moreover, in that sense, Levi was also blessed by Melchizedek, and the rule is that the lesser is blessed by the greater. (Heb 7:4-10)

Comment: The Konathites weren't priests.

Answer (score 4):

The (currently accepted) answer by @OzzieOzzie is just plain wrong.

## This has nothing to do with priesthood - but being a Rabbi

At this time, *one had to be approximately 30 years of age to become a Rabbi*. This recorded in the Code of Jewish Law (O.C. 581:1), which was being written at that time, along with the codification of the Talmud.

You can read more about this [over at mi yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8752/why-is-the-age-of-30-important-in-the-bible) where the user GershonGold comments:

> The Rashbam explains that at 30 one is worthy of leadership.... Orach Chaim 581:1 mentions that a Baal Tefila for the High Holy days should be at least 30. The Mishna Berura explains that at 30 one is humble and broken hearted.

Furthermore, in Jewish though, God had commanded people to "be fruitful and multiply" (you can read more about Talmudic ideas of this [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4013732/jewish/Be-Fruitful-and-Multiply-The-Commandment-to-Raise-Children.htm) and [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1005203/jewish/Be-Fruitful-and-Multiply.htm)), and although no one would want to *forbid* a man from becoming a Rabbi due to lack of being married and having children, it was *strongly encouraged*.  Of course this required you to be of an age - mid to late twenties - whereby you at least had the *opportunity* to experience "first mitzvot of the Torah" (ie, "be fruitful and multiply"). (Reference: this is mentioned in Satlow's Jewish Marriage in Antiquity, but it's a big book and I'll have hunt it down later).

There are more reasons (such as having to have experienced a significant amount of life, etc).  But ultimately **one could not lead a Rabbinical school, nor lead services on one of the High Holy days unless they were 30**.

Jesus - a Jewish Rabbi - would not have been accepted *at all* unless he was at that age.

### The problem with the priesthood claim

Jesus' lineage shows him being of the tribe of Judah; He is in line for being king. *He absolutely does NOT qualify as a priest*, who are required to be sons of Aaron (ie, Levites).

The reference to Jesus as "High Priest" is clearly stated as something *entirely separate from the Levitical regulations*.  Paul talks about this at length in Hebrews 5-7, and even the prophecies of the Messiah mention that Messiah would be a priest - but NOT of the sons of Aaron; Messiah would be "in the order of Melchizedek" (Psalm 110:4). In fact, Hebrews explicitly says Jesus was NOT of the Levitical order (Heb 7:11):

> If perfection could have been attained through the Levitical priesthood—and indeed the law given to the people established that priesthood—why was there still need for another priest to come, one in the order of Melchizedek, not in the order of Aaron?

There are no such requirements for "being of the order of Melchizedek".

This distinction is crucial, because there are differences in the priesthoods. For example:

- there is no maximum: Levites **aged-out at 50**; there is no maximum age for being in the order of Melchizedek (which means Jesus can be a High Priest forever)
- the Levites were required to keep people *away* from God. Only the High Priest could enter God's presence (and then only one day a year). Anyone who tried was to be killed on-site (hence all the guards). But Jesus' role is to bring people *into* God's presence.
- the Levites were forbidden from being king, and Jesus is described as the King of Israel

Comment: cegfault:Heb 8 :1-3NET  Better covenant
1 Now the main point of what we are saying is this: We have such a high priest, one who sat down at the right hand of the throne of the Majesty in heaven, 2 a minister in the sanctuary and the true tabernacle that the Lord, not man, set up. 3 For every high priest is appointed to offer both gifts and sacrifices. So this one too had to have something to offer. Num 4:3 KJV  From thirty years old and upward even until fifty years old, all that enter into the host, to do the work in the tabernacle of the congregation.(tent of meeting(Ex 25:8-9)

Comment: @OzzieOzzie you're quoting Heb 8.  How about you go back to Heb 7:11 *If perfection could have been attained through the Levitical priesthood—and indeed the law given to the people established that priesthood—why was there still need for another priest to come, one in the order of Melchizedek, not in the order of Aaron?*  We have "such a high priest" - what is "such" a high priest? *one of the order of Melchizedek*

Comment: cegfault:cegfault:Although the Law  given by God was perfect, neither the Law, its priesthood, nor the sacrifices brought perfection to those under the Law, as the inspired apostle shows. (Heb 7:11, 19; 10:1) Rather than bring freedom from sin and death, it actually made sin more evident. (Ro 3:20; 7:7-13) All these divine provisions, nevertheless, served the purpose assigned them by God; the Law acted as a “tutor” to lead men to Christ, forming a perfect “shadow of the good things to come.” (Gal .3:19-25; Heb 10:1)Hence, when Paul speaks of “an incapability on the part of the Law,

Comment: while it was weak through the flesh” (Rom 8:3), he is evidently referring to the inability of the fleshly Jewish high priest (who was appointed by the Law to be in charge of the sacrificial arrangements and who entered the Most Holy on Atonement Day with sacrificial blood) to “save completely” those whom he served, as Hebrews 7:11, 18-28 explains. Although the offering of sacrifices through the Aaronic priesthood maintained a right standing for the people before God, it did not completely or perfectly relieve them of consciousness of sin.

Comment: I agree that the priesthood angle is just wrong, mainly because the 30 year limit referenced in Numbers were for certain Levites working in the temple and not for the priest themselves. I'm not sold on the rabbinical angle since it's not scriptural and Jesus was primarily concerned with fulfilling the scriptures and not man made doctrines.

Answer (score 4):

Jesus's life and ministry often included events that reflect various messianic patterns established in the Old Testament. It turns out that the age at which Jesus began his ministry may also follow that trend.

**There are two messianic figures that both began their ministries at age 30.**

> **David when he began to reign:**
> *4 David was thirty years old when he began to reign, and he reigned forty years.*
> **-2 Samuel 5:4**

> **Joseph when he entered into the service of the Pharoah to save the world:**
> *46 Joseph was thirty years old when he entered the service of Pharaoh king of Egypt. And Joseph went out from the presence of Pharaoh and went through all the land of Egypt... 57 Moreover, all the earth came to Egypt to Joseph to buy grain, because the famine was severe over all the earth.*
> **-Genesis 41:46-57**

<sub>**NOTE:** Very fascinating book ***Messiah Ben Joseph*** by David Mitchell that details the Jewish tradition of the Messianic Joseph and his descendant Joshua that is deeply rooted in the Old Testament scripture.</sub>

<sub>**NOTE:** *Regarding other answers posted. I don't believe that the 30 year age requirement in Numbers 4 relates since none of those temple workers were priests and I also don't think Jesus's starting age has much to do with rabbinic tradition since Jesus was more considered with fulfilling the scriptures than the doctrines of men.*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Well since my last answer wasn't understood it seems I'll have to spell it out. Jesus died at **30 Years** because there exists prophecy in Scripture that Jesus would die after **5,500 Years** from Adam.

This timeline is embedded within the creation week of *Genesis 1:1-2:3* which represents an historical timeline of **7,000 Years**. This is because God told Adam:

> "but from the Tree of the Knowledge of Good and Evil you shall not eat, for *in* the day you eat if it you will surely die."
> *Genesis 2:17* (emphasis added mine)

And when did Adam die?

> "So all the days that Adam lived were 930 Years, and he died."
> *Genesis 5:5*

Seeing that Adam died ***in*** the day he ate of the forbidden fruit: each day of the week represents a period of **1,000 Years**. So then God from the very beginning wrote that there would only be **7,000 Years** of recorded history.

And we see that Adam was created in the middle of the **6th Day** while the animals of the earth were created in the beginning of the same day (*Genesis 1:26-28*); and, while not explicitly stated we can draw this conclusion from the fact that instead of God creating everything instantly He spread out everything over a **6 Day** period, and since this is so we may also safely say that it took God some time to form all of the animals; and, and since this is so it is not hard to believe that God gave Adam dominion over all the animals and the earth at the end of the **6th Day**.

All this means that after **5,500 Years** Christ would die and rise from the dead: this we see in the creation week for exactly **3 Days** and **3 Nights** prior man did not exist and God was creating the earth and the plant life from the ground (*Genesis 1:9-13*). And when Adam was created from the dust of the ground: this is a shadow of Jesus Christ's resurrection from the dead. Adam is a type of Christ for he and Eve are the only people to not have earthly parents give birth to them, therefore this makes Adam the Son of God and the first type of Christ who is the new Adam. And after **6,000 Years** Christ would return to rule the earth for **1,000 Years**.

We also see proof of this in the dimensions of the Ark of the Covenant, in cubits, which add up to **5.5 Cubits** (*Exodus 37:1*) which are **5,500 Years** before Christ would come in the flesh and die for our sins. The final proof of Christ dying **5500 AM** is in Daniel's **70 Week** prophecy where he gives us the exact year Christ would die:

> "So you are to know and discern that from the issuing of a decree to restore and rebuild Jerusalem until Messiah the Prince there will be seven weeks and sixty-two weeks; it will be built again, with plaza and moat, even in times of distress. Then after the sixty-two weeks the Messiah will be cut off and have nothing, and the people of the prince who is to come will destroy the city and the sanctuary. And its end will come with a flood; even to the end there will be war; desolations are determined."
> *Daniel 9:25-26*

So this means that Daniel is beginning his count from the time of Cyrus the great as he foresees the delays in temple construction, being done in times of distress, and therefore says this will happen in a **7 Week/49 Year** period; that is why he says after **62 Weeks/434 Years** the Messiah will die (see [interlinear Hebrew to confirm that *Messiah*, and not *Prince*, is used)](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/daniel/9-26.htm).

Now if we count all of the years from Adam to the death of Christ according to the longer chronology in the *Septuagint/LXX* then we get **5,500 Years**; but according to the shorter chronology found in the *Masoretic Text* there are **4,034 Years** for the same period. Here is a breakdown of the *LXX* reckoning:

- **2,242 Years (Adam to Flood)**
- **1,247 Years (Flood to Abraham)**
- **430 Years (Abraham to Moses)**
- **511 Years (Moses to Saul)**
- **517 Years (Saul to Babylon)**
- **70 Years (Babylon to Cyrus)**
- **483 Years (Cyrus to Christ)**

Cyrus began his reign in the year **5017 AM** and **483 Years** later Christ would die **5500 AM**. We may verify this to be true when we look at the reigns of Augustus and Tiberius. Augustus came into power in the **184th Olympiad** while Christ died in the **202nd Olympiad**, which is also the **15th Year** of Tiberius. Therefore this is a span of **72 Years** which means Jesus was **15 Years** old at the death of Augustus and the **1st Year** of Tiberius; and died at **30 Years** old in the **15th Year** of Tiberius. This then would mean that the Ptolemaic dynasty lasted for only **280 Years**; Alexander the Great ruled for **12 Years** from the **111th Olympiad** to the **114th Olympiad**; and from Cyrus to the end of the Persian kingdom is **119 Years**. And **1 Olympiad = 4 Years**.

So it is clear that God planned for Jesus to die at **30 Years** old **5,500 Years** from Adam. And when you check the time of His death against history it all adds up. And finally this prophecy was given cryptically to Adam and Eve when they were in the garden of Eden:

> "And I will put enmity between you and the woman, and between your seed and her seed; He shall bruise you on the head, and you shall bruise Him on the heel.”
> *Genesis 3:15*

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple answer: **John the Baptist had to come first and fulfill the role of Elijah.**

> The disciples asked him, “Then why do the scribes say that first
> Eli′jah must come?”  He replied, “Eli′jah does come, and he is to
> restore all things; but I tell you that Eli′jah has already come, and
> they did not know him, but did to him whatever they pleased... 13 Then
> the disciples understood that he was speaking to them of John the
> Baptist.

The reason that religious authorities insisted Elijah much come before the Messiah is the prophecy of Malachi 4:5-6

> Behold, I will send you Eli′jah the prophet before the great and
> terrible day of the Lord comes. And he will turn the hearts of fathers to their children and the hearts of children to their fathers, lest I come and smite the land with a curse.

We don't know exactly how long John's ministry lasted before Jesus came to be baptized by him. But apparently he had done enough, even though he had not yet 'restored all things' for Jesus to feel that it was time to begin his own ministry on John's foundation as his forerunner.